# How to place image to left, with text to the right

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin called "List Category Posts" in use, but I have some issues with the customization of that list.

Post-titles containing a specific amount of characters are now flowing around my thumbnails, but they do not start on the same height as the thumbnails. I want my thumbnails in the top left position, just like that:

[img] text text

[Location of that list](http://www.filmfutter.com/78494-2/)

Code snippet in my style.css:

```
.post-content ul.lcp_catlist li { background-image: none; padding-left: 0;clear:both;} 
.lcp_thumbnail{ float:left; margin:0px 10px 5px 0px; height: 100px; width:100px;}
.lcp_catlist li:after {content:'.';height:20px;visibility:hidden;display:block;clear:both; } 
.lcp_title{font-size: 20px;}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it listed like the second item on the site?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the template, you should place the img tag before the title.
This way everything will work exactly as you want it to.

If you can't access the template you could float the title to the right.

```
.lcp_title { float: right; width: 472px; }
```

This ought to solve the problem as well.
Let me know how it works out.

Comment: I do not have access to the template, but the "float: right" statement works fine. Many thanks, you saved me a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the image always on the left you need to move the `<a>` tag to the first thing listed within the `li`.  The CSS is fine.